# Negating types in Flow

Tags: flowtype

I have a union type like this:

```
type ActionTypes = "ACTION_ONE" | "ACTION_TWO" | "ACTION_THREE"
```

And now I wonder if I can type that variable **will be a string but none of the above**?

for example:

```
const myStr: ActionTypes = "something" // no error
const myStr2: ActionTypes = "ACTION_ONE" // error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> tl;dr: Maybe with type assertions, but it's hard to use effectively

I don't think there's a straightforward/possible way to exclude string literals from the `string` type. You *might* consider doing a [type assertion](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/#toc-type-assertions) of the variable by (ab)using [`$Call<F, T>`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-call), but this technique is almost certainly a bad idea:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYBVwQM5QLxQBEMAwugJIDyAcgPo0CihUAPkaRTbegOqXNtiZKnXQAJAEoMmAKBmhIUamnhI0AMQCuqOJkgAedAD58MqFAAUhgFywEKDFmxGL6AJT4TAMwCGAG2wIDwAySxsobGAAJ0RUAHMXd08oaM0ggG45ODRIqDjkZAATfCIAIz8fAAtCTItUiFsAEhJ-P31lVFUHLR09CH0FCGQvPILCowAaFKxh0aKjDwB6RagABR9sQOwsnOAoUp9C2yFOOkZmAhORemomWvqmlr82jq6NbV0sAZmRg-GpwazP4LKDLKDqHyIAIyIA))

```
type ActionTypes = "ACTION_ONE" | "ACTION_TWO" | "ACTION_THREE"

type NonActionFuncType<T> =
  (<T: ActionTypes>(T) => false) & (<T: string>(T) => true);

const good = "blah";
(true: $Call<NonActionFuncType<typeof good>, typeof good>) // Passes

const bad: "ACTION_ONE" = "ACTION_ONE";
(true: $Call<NonActionFuncType<typeof bad>, typeof bad>) // Fails
```

Pragmatically, I would suggest you look for another way to do whatever you're looking to do. Flow automatically types all string literals as `string` unless you specify the type, so this sort of technique won't catch too many bugs (*unless you're passing variables with a literal string type, which you might be doing*).

Comment: I'm struggling to type redux action in a reducer because some of the actions are created dynamically. Anyway, thanks!